# regex for pattern in java

Tags: java, regex

I need regex (named in code myRegex) which will match all functions (function1, function2, function3).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String template = "f[0-9]"; // like f1, f2 etc
    String myRegex = "fun\\((" + template + "*)\\)"; //todo what regex?
    Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile(myRegex);

    String function1 = "fun(f1)";
    String function2 = "fun(f1,f9)"; //myRegex don't match
    String function3 = "fun(f1,f9,f4)"; // myRegex don't match

    List<String> functions = Lists.asList(function1, function2, function3);
    for (String function : functions) {
        Matcher matcher = myPattern.matcher(function);
        while (matcher.find())
        {
            System.out.println(function + " match!");//works only for function1
        }
    }

}
```

Elements in brackets must be seperated by comma (,).
It must work for other funcions with many arguments like
:function4 = "fun(f1,f9,f4,f5,f7)";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below.

```
String myRegex = "fun\\((" + template + ",)*" + template + "?\\)";
```

If you want to cater to fun() as well - without any parameters,  use below

```
String myRegex = "fun\\((" + template + ",)*(" + template + ")?\\)";
```

Comment: And if you need to also factor for fun(), then you can use the updated solution as well..

Comment: Note that the first regex also matches `fun(f)` while the second one also matches `fun(f1,)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex pattern:

```regex
fun\(f[0-9](?:,f[0-9]){0,2}\)
```

This will match any function named `fun()` having between 1 and 3 `f` arguments.  Your actual Java regex pattern should be defined as:

```java
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("fun\\(f[0-9](?:,f[0-9]){0,2}\\)");
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for editing my post after your answer. (Until my edit it was correct answer)

Answer (score 0):

### Regex

Use the following regex. It will also work if there are spaces between arguments or parentheses:

```
fun\s*\(\s*(?:f[0-9])?(?:\s*,\s*f[0-9])*\s*\)
```

### Demo

https://regex101.com/r/hndzov/1

### Java string

```
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("fun\\s*\\(\\s*(?:f[0-9])?(?:\\s*,\\s*f[0-9])*\\s*\\)")
```

### Explanation

---

| Regex | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `fun` | Match exactly the characters `fun` |
| `\s` | Match any whitespace character |
| `\s*` | Match 0 or more whitespaces |
| `\(`, `\(` | Match opening and closing parentheses |
| `f` | Match character `f` |
| `[0-9]` | Match any digit from 0-9 |
| `(?:)` | Make a group but don't capture it |

### Cons

Also matches a parameter list with a leading comma like `fun(,f2, f3)`.